# How to remove Bitmap in AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, bitmap, actionscript-2

I have added a bitmap in movieclip using attachBitmap in my Flash Actionscript 2 project. Now i am having trouble to remove bitmap that is created once. If anyone can give idea how can i do this.

Thank you
Imran

Answer (score 0):

Try with .clear();  This will clear everything drawn on top of the movie clip.
More info here: "http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001277.html"

Answer (score 0):

yourBitmapData.dispose() will do the job.